# tezos-node command to check context & store integrity

Tags: node, storage

Is there a way to check if context and store data folders are corrupted or not via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out the experimental `tezos-node storage integrity-check` (see `tezos-node storage --help`):

```
$ ./tezos-node storage integrity-check -d /tmp/tezos-node.jqKo0RB7/
Running the integrity_check.
    2k contents / 8k nodes / 0k commits
Ok
```

where `-d <datadir>` is used to give the storage directory of your node. It seems that node can't be running when you do the integrity check.